# javascript string variable works, variable of object[key] doesn't

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object

this part of a script to draw a d3 chart works:

```
var data = [
{"day":1,"Dollars":392262,"Pesos":22122},{"day":2,"Dollars":402544,"Pesos":22157},
etc.
];
    //code, then
x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.day; }));
```

As long as the word "day" appears in the last line, no problem. However, it's not always "day." It might be "hour" or it might be "month." So I don't want any word hard coded in, I want a variable in its place; that variable would tell whether it's day or hour or month.

So I tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
var data = [
{"day":1,"Dollars":392262,"Pesos":22122},{"day":2,"Dollars":402544,"Pesos":22157},
etc.
];
key =  Object.keys(data[0]);
period_grain = key[0]; //alerts 'day' (no quotes)
    //code, then
x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.period_grain; }));
```

Obviously it's the way I'm using `period_grain` but after research I still can't figure out how to use it properly.

Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: `return d[period_grain]`

Comment: that worked, thanks very much. Also, the other question of which this was a duplicate gives a good description of how to deal with this